# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error.json is not a function - while destructing error message

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, async-await

I'm working on React Redux app,

I'm getting *"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error.json is not a function"* error, while trying to destruct error messages from the return API error. My API returns an error with the following structure:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|5f13e001-48d7893e3cc8e8ff.",
  "errors": {
    "Code": [
      "'Code' must not be empty."
    ],
    "Name": [
      "'Name' must not be empty."
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how I handle save method:

```
  const handleSave = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSaving(true);
    saveTeam(team)
      .then(() => {
        showSnackbar("Team was saved successfully");
        history.push("/teams");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        let errorMessage = error.message.json();
        debugger;

        setErrors({ onSave: error.message }); //<---- In here I want to pass just the list of errors 
        setSaving(false);
      });
  };
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error.message.json is not a function
```

BTW. I'm passing `error.message` to `SetErrors` and later I'm printing it on the screen. This is what I'm getting:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|5f13e004-48d7893e3cc8e8ff.","errors":{"Code":["'Code' must not be empty."],"Name":["'Name' must not be empty."]}}
```

So `error.message` is what I'm looking for... but how can I destruct it?

Comment: If `errors.message` returns the object you're showing - `{"type": ...}`, then you should use `JSON.parse` if it's not already a `JavaScript` object, or just do pick whatever property you want for the error message, for example `error.title`

Comment: Can you clarify why you are specifically trying to execute json() on error? What is give you the impression it should have a json() method? What happens if you just console.log(error)?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I want to get list of errors. console.log(error.message) prints a string that has a json format

Comment: Okay, if you console.log(error.message) what logs out? Why are you trying to execute a method json()?

Comment: @IshThomas have you tried doing `JSON.parse(error.message)` to turn that `JSON` into a plain `JavaScript` object so that you can grab whatever property you need?

Comment: @goto1 Actually `JSON.parse` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `error.message` is actually `JSON`, you should use `JSON.parse` to parse a `JSON` string into a `JavaScript` object:

```js
const error = {
  message: JSON.stringify({
    type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    title: "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    status: 400,
    traceId: "|5f13e004-48d7893e3cc8e8ff.",
    errors: {
      Code: ["'Code' must not be empty."],
      Name: ["'Name' must not be empty."]
    }
  })
};
console.log(error.message);

// use destructing assignment to unpack properties from the object
const { type, title, status } = JSON.parse(error.message);

console.log("");
console.log("type", type);
console.log("title", title);
console.log("status", status);
```

Going back to your code, it should look like the following:

```js
const handleSave = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setSaving(true);
  saveTeam(team)
    .then(() => {
      showSnackbar("Team was saved successfully");
      history.push("/teams");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      const { errors }  = JSON.parse(error.message);
      let allErrors = [];

      for (const [key, array] of Object.entries(errors)) {
        // use `spread syntax` to combine all error messages
        allErrors = [...allErrors, ...array]
      }
      setErrors({ onSave: allErrors.join(";") });
      // 'Code' must not be empty.;'Name' must not be empty. 

      setSaving(false);
    });
};
```

References:

- [Destructing assignment - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [JSON.parse() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [Spread syntax (...) - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because simply your `json` object has no property of type `function` to invoke
you can destructure a json object like this

```js
var jsonob={
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|5f13e001-48d7893e3cc8e8ff.",
  "errors": {
    "Code": [
      "'Code' must not be empty."
    ],
    "Name": [
      "'Name' must not be empty."
    ]
  }
}

const {type,title,status,traceId,errors}=jsonob
console.log(type,title,status,traceId,errors)
```